# TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript

I was toying with the number object and I came up with this code (I know this is not good practice):

```
Number.prototype.times = function (evalString) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this; i++) {
    eval(evalString);
  }
}
//var someVar= 3;
(8).times("alert('kek')");
```

and it seems to work only when the someVar variable is not commented out, otherwise it throws the error in the title.

What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Placing `(...)` immediately after a function expression (`function (evalString) { … }`) will *call* the function with the arguments you specify.

This is why depending on automatic semicolon insertion is not recommended. Always end your statements with a `;`.

Comment: Not recommended by some * 

Comment: @RayonDabre — "Don't depend on automatic semicolon insertion"

Comment: I don't understand. I don't have those three dots (`...`) in the line. But, I got this error. I also always end the statements with `;`. Or do I have to put `;` in every line?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi — The 3 dots just mean "There might be some arguments here". I meant what I said, put a semicolon after each statement, not each line.

Comment: Just faced this issue in production when it worked fine in development. Only difference, production had the minified version where without the `;` the code looked like a 'function()()' which was causing the issue. Always end with `;` especially if you use uglify/minify.