# Why is error in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this code return an error.

```
 var old_newOther = newOther;
 consoleParse = function(e){
    old_newOther(e);
 }
 (function($) {
 newOther = function(e){
   for(var k in e){
     if(isset(e[k].onMouseDown)){
        TalkWithNPC(e[k].id);
     }
   }
   return e;
 }})(jQuery);
```

> VM413:29 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a
>   function(…)

Answer (score 0):

You forget to inset `;` before function expression.

Placing (...) immediately after a function expression consoleParse = (function(e){
    old_newOther(e);
 })  will call the function with the arguments you specify.

This is why depending on automatic semicolon insertion is not recommended. Always end your statements with a `;`.

Comment: This is the same issue that in 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278393/typeerror-intermediate-value-is-undefined